# phonegap childbrowser iphone build issues

Tags: iphone, cordova

There has been some recent updates to the child browser plugin, when i try to compile it for Iphone and phonegap 1.4.1 I get build errors.

```
@property declaration not in @interface or @implementation



#ifdef PHONEGAP_FRAMEWORK
 @interface ChildBrowserCommand : PGPlugin <ChildBrowserDelegate> {
#endif
#ifdef CORDOVA_FRAMEWORK
 @interface ChildBrowserCommand : CDVPlugin <ChildBrowserDelegate> {
#endif
ChildBrowserViewController* childBrowser;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) ChildBrowserViewController *childBrowser;
 - (void) showWebPage:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;
 -(void) onChildLocationChange:(NSString*)newLoc;
@end
```

Comment: can u tell me Error Message...!

Comment: Kind of figured out the issue, the plugins have been update for the latest phonegap 1.5  version and do not compile in Xcode 3.2.6 so shifted to an older version provided by https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone